# Get data from string

Tags: regex

i have a string like

A & A COMPUTERS INC [RC1058054]

i want a regex to split all the data inside [ ]  .Any ideas ?

Comment: Some clarification is in order, IMO. What output do you want? How does "split RC1058054" look like (`RC`,`1058054` or perhaps: `R`,`C`,`1`,`0`,`5`,`8`,`0`,`5`,`4`)? Also, what language are you using? (yes, it matters).

Comment: Please hover over the regex tag and read the tag-wiki.

Comment: do you want to extract content inside [] brackets ? please provide 2-3 input strings and corrosponding output so that we will be able to help you in correct manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex `(?<=\[)[^]]*(?=\])` capture all data between `[` and `]` for .net and java platform.

Comment: No, it does not: your suggestion does not mandate there to be a closing `]` :)

Answer (score 1):

To capture the data between `[` and `]` you can use the regex:

```
\[([^]]*)\]
```

Comment: Is that what `split all the data inside [ ]` means? If you're right, you must tell me your brand of crystal ball: I'm getting one as well! :)

Comment: it is not valid, this regex also captures [ and ].

Comment: @Gursel, the stuff between `[` and `]` is captured in `$1`. IMO it makes the regex far less readable to introduce look arounds. Besides, the OP might be using a regex implementation that does not support look behinds (or look-arounds in general).

Answer (score 1):

Since the current version of the question leaves out the programming language, I just pick one.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "A & A COMPUTERS INC [RC1058054]"
>>> re.search("\[(.*)\]", s).group(1)
'RC1058054'

>>> # If you want to "split all data" ...
>>> [ x for x in re.search(s).group(1) ]
['R', 'C', '1', '0', '5', '8', '0', '5', '4']
```